# Error: socket hang up with socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

With Socket.IO,  i got error in server side as below:

> WARNING:: Error: socket hang up
>       at createHangUpError (http.js:1360:15)
>       at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage._writeRaw (http.js:507:26)
>       at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage._send (http.js:476:15)
>       at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.write (http.js:749:16)
>       at XHRPolling.doWrite (node_modules\socket.io\lib\transports
>   \xhr-polling.js:67:17)
>       at XHRPolling.HTTPPolling.write (node_modules\socket.io\lib\
>   transports\http-polling.js:132:82
>       at XHRPolling.Transport.onDispatch (node_modules\socket.io\l
>   ib\transport.js:222:10)
>       at Manager.onDispatch (\node_modules\socket.io\lib\manager.js
>   :392:31)
>       at SocketNamespace.packet (\node_modules\socket.io\lib\namesp
>   ace.js:156:16)
>       at SocketNamespace.emit (\node_modules\socket.io\lib\namespac
>   e.js:188:15)
>       at \gbin1platform\server-version1-broadcast-20131016.js:263:2
>   9
>       at Client.get (\node_modules\socket.io\lib\stores\memory.js:8
>   6:3)
>       at Socket.get (\node_modules\socket.io\lib\socket.js:258:14)

and i add code below to catch the socket hang up error , otherwise the application will exit:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (exception) {
  // handle or ignore error
  error(exception.stack);
});
```

but with code above, it cannot really handle socket handup error, only ensure the application won't crash, and code won't work anymore. How can i really solve the error above?